# Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, directory, include, eigen

My main.cpp file

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main(){

    std::vector<int> vec = {5,4,9,1,3,5};
    Eigen::MatrixXd my_matrix(2,3);
    my_matrix << 4,9,-7,
                5,-4,11;

    return 0;
}
```

My c_cpp_properties.json file

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "D:\\Master Program\\Self-Driving-Cars_Udacity\\Part1\\Module_05_Sensor_Fusion\\eigen-3.4.0\\"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

My task.json file

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-I",
                "D:\\Master Program\\Self-Driving-Cars_Udacity\\Part1\\Module_05_Sensor_Fusion\\eigen-3.4.0\\"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: In this folder `D:\\Master Program\\Self-Driving-Cars_Udacity\\Part1\\Module_05_Sensor_Fusion\\eigen-3.4.0` is there an `Eigen` folder containing a file name `Dense`?

Comment: Did you search for related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code+eigen

Comment: yes, but it doesn't help. I tried what they did but it was in vain